# Package synchronization with opkg

Tags: beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux, opkg

We're using the BeagleBone Black running Angstrom Linux and the opkg package manager to power some of our systems. We need to ensure that we have consistent and reliable access to specific versions of opkg packages. I've set up an in-house opkg repository. Is there any way to sync packages between repositories ? e.g. I'd like to copy specific packages from public / not always accessible repositories to our internal repository, both for speed and reliable access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fooling around with various packages, etc, I found a way of cloning (parts of) a repository using an Ubuntu system. Here's the steps I took:

```
# Install apache
sudo apt-get install apache2

# Install git
sudo apt-get install git

# Download the opkg-utils from the Yocto Project
git clone http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/opkg-utils

# Build the opkg-utils
cd opkg-utils && make; cd -

# Move them to a common directory
mv opkg-utils /usr/local/share\

# Add them to my path
echo "PATH=\"\$PATH:/usr/local/share/opkg-utils\"" >> /etc/environment

# Update my environment
source /etc/environment

# Create the structure of my repository
mkdir -p /var/www/repositories/opkg/beaglebone

# Create an index for the packages
opkg-make-index -l Packages.filelist -p Packages /var/www/repositories/opkg/beaglebone
cd /var/www/repositories/opkg/beaglebone
gzip -c Packages > Packages.gz
```

On my client BeagleBone Blacks, to setup access to this repository:

```
echo "src/gz reponame http://myserver/repositories/opkg/beaglebone" > /etc/opkg/rms-feed.conf
chmod 666 /etc/opkg/reponame-feed.conf
opkg update
```

On my developer machines, any time I need to backup a package:

```
#!/bin/bash

###############################################################################
#
# bbb_clone_package_to_internal_repo.sh
#
# Description:
# Clones an ipkg / opkg package to the internal repository server so that it can be deployed 
# to BeagleBone Black clients on demand. This is so that we can have backups in
# the event that a public server becomes temporarily or permanently 
# inaccessible.
#
# Pre-conditions:
# 1) The given package file must exist at the path specified. 
#
# Post-conditions:
# 1) The given package file will be sent to the internal repository server.
# 2) The opkg repository indexes will all be updated 
#
# Parameters:
# -p <file path.opk> : The package to be cloned
#
###############################################################################

PACKAGE_FILE_PATH=""
SERVER="myserver"

ERR_INVALID_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME=1
ERR_PACKAGE_FILE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE=2
ERR_FAILED_TO_COPY_PACKAGE_TO_SERVER=3
ERR_FAILED_TO_DEPLOY_PACKAGE_ON_SERVER=4

usage()
{
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

This script copies a remote ipkg/opkg file to the $SERVER server for subsequent
deployment to BeagleBone Black boards.

OPTIONS:
    -p <file path.[io]pk>   The package file to be deployed

    -h,?                    Show this message

EOF
}

while getopts “p:h?” OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
    p)
        PACKAGE_FILE_PATH="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    h)
        usage
        exit
        ;;
    ?)
        usage
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z "$PACKAGE_FILE_PATH" || ! ( "$PACKAGE_FILE_PATH" =~ \.[io]pk$ ) ]]; then
    echo "The package file must not be blank and must have an .ipk or .opk suffix"
    exit $ERR_INVALID_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME
fi

# Retrieve the package
wget -q "$PACKAGE_FILE_PATH"
RESULT="$?"
if [[ $RESULT -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Failed to retrieve file $PACKAGE_FILE_PATH with result $RESULT"
    exit $ERR_PACKAGE_FILE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
fi 

# Deploy the package to myserver 

PACKAGE_FILE_NAME="$(basename $PACKAGE_FILE_PATH)"
REPOSITORY_ROOT="/var/www/repositories/opkg/beaglebone"
scp "$PACKAGE_FILE_NAME" root@$SERVER:$REPOSITORY_ROOT
RESULT="$?"
if [[ $RESULT -ne 0 ]]; then

    echo "Failed to copy file $PACKAGE_FILE_NAME to server with result $RESULT"
    exit $ERR_FAILED_TO_COPY_PACKAGE_TO_SERVER
fi 

ssh root@$SERVER "chmod 644 $REPOSITORY_ROOT/$PACKAGE_FILE_NAME; opkg-make-index -l $REPOSITORY_ROOT/Packages.filelist -p $REPOSITORY_ROOT/Packages -r $REPOSITORY_ROOT/Packages $REPOSITORY_ROOT && gzip -c $REPOSITORY_ROOT/Packages > $REPOSITORY_ROOT/Packages.gz"
RESULT="$?"
if [[ $RESULT -ne 0 ]]; then

    echo "Failed to deploy file $PACKAGE_FILE_NAME in repository with result $RESULT"
    exit $ERR_FAILED_TO_DEPLOY_PACKAGE_ON_SERVER
fi 

exit 0
```

Comment: Tip for using the script: setup public key authentication between your machine and the server to avoid having to enter passwords repeatedly when using the script.